# mover el boton dropdown de la derecha a la izquierda

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Como puedo mover el boton dropdown que aparece ubicado en la derecha del dropdown menú, hacia la izquierda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: "Podrias dejar algo de codigo para saber por donde empezar, puede ser o el css o el html. Un float o la posicion en la que se pone el icono. Detalla tu pregunta por favor." - Andoni Alda

Comment: Kayo, bienvenido a Stakckoverflow en español. Por favor edita tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía: [mcve].

Comment: Kayo, como dicen los otros comentarios, puedes añadir el codigo [tag:HTML] que se genera de tu `dropdown`? una vez añadido se votará para reabrir la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: ¿Demasiado amplia? Solamente hay dos opciones: 1. Poner el `span.caret` en primer lugar y el texto después. 2. Sobreescribir los estilos para el `.btn` de `.dropdown`.